# Compiled Linq to SQL Queries in MVC Webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, datacontext, linq.compiledquery

I have build a web application with mvc 4. First i implemented the application without compiled queries but to increase the performance i want to use compiled queries.
But i can´t use the queries because of the `DataContext`.
I have a class for the queries with a lot of methods like:

```
    private static Func<DataContext, int, IEnumerable<Information>> _OwnInformations;
    public static List<Information> GetOwnInformations(DataContext dataContext, int userId)
    {
        if (_OwnInformations == null)
        {
            _OwnInformations = CompiledQuery.Compile<DataContext, int, IEnumerable<Information>>((dc, id) => (
                 from tm in dc.GetTable<Information>()
                 where tm.User.Id == id || tm.Author.Id == id
                 select tm
                 ));
        }
            return _OwnInformations.Invoke(dataContext, userId).Distinct().ToList();
    }
```

The `DataContext` is created and disposed in the `Controller` classes. So i have the problem that it isn´t possible to use a compiled query with different `DataContext`s .
Also i don´t want to take the `DataContext` in the session.

Have anybody an idea to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem. I needed an own DataContext partial class with my tables and the connection within. So, now i can use my compiled queries :).